# Redirect to a subdirectory

Tags: url, redirect

Can anyone tell me how to automatically redirect the visitor to a subdirectory of my website (subdirectory contains index.html so no need to type /index.html in url)?

For instance my file structure is like this:

public_html/index.html <-- empty file, just contains URL redirect code to /stageforduets

public_html/stageforduets/index.html

I don't want the visitor to have to type in www.mywebsite.com/stageforduets every time. I want the visitor to type in www.mywebsite.com then automatically redirect to www.mywebsite.com/colorfulstage (not www.mywebsite.com/stageforduets/index.html)

I've already tried

```
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://www.mywebsite.com/stageforduets/index.html">
```

but it's not working. It's giving a

"Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /stageforduetsstageforduetsstageforduetsstageforduetsstageforduetsstageforduetsstageforduetsstageforduetsstageforduetsstageforduetsstageforduetsstageforduetsstageforduetsstageforduetsstageforduetsstageforduetsstageforduetsstageforduetsstageforduetsstageforduets on this server." error. O_o

Thanks.

Comment: We need more of the code. The refresh code you posted should work fine.

Comment: Can you post your /stageforduets/index.html file?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use php header to solve this problem?

Comment: The OP is not using .php files.